# What happens when we try to call a garbage collected function in JavaScript? Like a "dead" listener from an iframe that is no longer in the page

Tags: javascript, garbage-collection

I've been getting a weird bug in the past days, which I think is related to this.

- I have the main page that renders an iframe.
- The `iframe` renders and sets up a listener on the main page.
- At some point the `iframe` goes away (its url changes)
- The `iframe` does not have the opportunity to unsubscribe the listener
- Host page receives event and tries to call the "dead" listener

  - Probably garbage collected, because the process inside the iframe that created the function no longer exists
- Browser freezes and no error is being logged.

Could this be related to my bug?

Or calling a "dead" listener is just the same as trying to call an `undefined` value?

---

**UPDATE**

Yeah, it looks like this is the source of my problem. I added a code for my pubsub to log how many listeners it's trying to dispatch the event to.

And I'm getting way more listeners than I was supposed to have (I was expecting only two. One for the parent and one for the iframe). It publishes just fine for the 1st one (from the parent page), but the code kind of freezes on the second (which is probably from a dead iframe). I even wrapped it in a `try{} catch{}` but it does not `throw` any thing. It just freezes!

Comment: You can't call a garbage collected function. If you can obtain the function to call it, there still is some alive reference to it - unless you're using weak references - and it thus can't have been garbage collected in the first place, no matter where it was created.

Comment: A browser freeze most likely indicates an infinite loop, an extremely inefficient algorithm (e.g. RegEx blowing up) or the like.

Comment: How does the iframe register an event on the main page? Are you using window.postMessage? And events registered on the main page are registered in the context of the main page, so even if the iframe dies, the event can still live on. I am not sure if it can freeze your page.

Comment: I'm not sure if that browser freezes because of the function not existing. Can you reproduce the issue on codesandbox? About trying to call garbage-collected function, we can try to reproduce it with [WeakRef](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/WeakRef)

Comment: Thank you all for your comments. I'll do some further investigation today and let you know. The iframe is in the same domain, so it has access to the parent's window object. The iframe access a PubSub (on the parent's window) to subscribe to an event. Then the iframe "dies" (as intended).